# Deleting Multiple rows from a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: modifying view when user shakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955943/iphone-modifying-view-when-user-shakes)

hi Frnz,

i want to delete multiple rows from a table view based on users selection.obviously i cant use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method coz it will be called for every row selected. i want to allow user to select multiple rows for deletion and then delete them in one go...Is it possible if yes then how to go about it.Also i am using a single view based project and i want the header of table view changed to "Delete" on the same view when the user want to delete the rows from the view.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: but you need to keep a little state for each row selected for deletion.  Once you have set the state for each row selected for deletion, and the user triggers the delete all action, you can remove all the rows that have their state set.

Comment: i dint got what u said..can u explain it a level further...